# Section titles in caps give problems with math mode in it

Tags: math-mode, sectioning

I use the style file mn2e that makes section titles appear in boldface and in all caps.  Which is fine, but not for the formula within such a title.

Example:

```
\section{The derivative $dI/dR$}
```

gives as output

> APPENDIX B: THE DERIVATIVE DI/DR

So the math mode remains, which is good, but now also the derivation "d" has been capitalized, which obviously shouldn't be the case.

This seems like a pretty standard problem, but I couldn't find the answer here, so sorry if this is a previously answered question.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What document class (or style file) are you using?

Comment: One should know at least which class/style file is used in order to help.

Comment: this might reasonably be reported as a bug to the author of the offending document class or package.

Answer (score 3):

You might try adding this at the end of your preamble (works for me, but might depend on the style/class file in use):

```
\usepackage{textcase}
\let\MakeUppercase\MakeTextUppercase
```

and optionally:

```
\let\MakeLowercase\MakeTextLowercase
```

Comment: isn't there an option to `textcase` that does that change automatically?

Comment: @daleif Yes, `\usepackage[overload]{textcase}`